# XMLHttpRequest not working properly in Safari (but works with Chrome)

Tags: safari, xmlhttprequest

I have the following code to load a file after creating a web page which displays a WebGL canvas:

```
// Load ccconnect.js file
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
            eval.call( Window, xmlhttp.response );
        }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET","../ccconnect.js",true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

It works fine in Chrome but Safari brings up an error saying:

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Window

on the line `eval.call(...)`. The `ccconnect.js` code is displayed when I hover the mouse over '`response`' on that same line when debugging so it seems to have retrieved it. Any idea what is wrong? I'm using Safari 5.1.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

both `window` and `Window` is the global object both are understand by other browsers.

but when I checked in safari, it don't understand the variable `Window`. So my suggestion is replace `Window` with `window`.